# How to determine true/false sharing misses in cache coherence?

Tags: multithreading, caching, concurrency

I have a question regarding True/False sharing miss in Cache coherence.

Xl and X2 are in the block B. The block B is initially in the private caches of processors Pl and P2. The system uses MSI protocol. The following sequence of events are given

1. P2 writes Xl,
2. P2 reads X2,
3. Pl reads X2,
4. P2 writes Xl,
5. P1 writes X2,
6. P2 reads X2.

I figured out that (3) will be false sharing miss, as (1) invalidated the copy of B in P1 even though there was no change in value of X2. And (6) should be True sharing miss as (5) updated X2 and it needs to be communicated to P2.

How to categorise others ( as True/False sharing miss) ? A good explanation for each categorisation is appreciated.

I am really confused with True sharing miss concept. False sharing miss is so easy to understand.

If more information required, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your terminology.  In *false sharing*, the meaning of *false* is *incorrect*, rather than a boolean or logical fallacy.  Typically, to analyze it, you look at the *state* the block will be in after each op; and the transactions for achieving that state. For example, assuming MESI cache protocol:

```
op#  P1   P2   Trans
 0    I    I   0          -- assume invalid to start
 1    I    M   R+I
 2    I    M   0
 3    S    S   r  
 4    I    M   X
 5    M    I   r+I
 6    S    S   r
```

The transactions are R=system Read, I=Invalidate, r=local Read.  If you are an arm-type, think system = outer, local = inner.  So we see 1*Read + 3*cacheread + 2*Invalidate; or, condensed, 3 system, 3 local.

Now, if we assume X1 & X2 were in separate blocks

```
op#   P1     P2       Trans
 0    I,I    I,I       
 1    I,I    M,I      R+I
 2    I,I    M,S      R
 3    I,S    M,S      r
 4    I,S    M,S      0
 5    I,M    M,I      R+I             
 6    I,S    M,S      r
```

we see 3*Read 2*cread 2*Invalidate; or 5 system, 2 local.
From that, it appears that placing X1, X2 into separate blocks will not appreciably improve this workload.  Even if the Invalidate + Read were collapsed,